# Google Sheets API localhost refused to connect when authorizing

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I was going through the [Quickstart for Nodejs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) and every time I run the code, I get this.

[image]

I've tried things like rebooting the computer, making new credentials, making new projects but nothing worked.

What might be the problem?

Also, I'm using a mac.

Comment: Could you be more precise about when the error occurs? From what I understand after running `node index.js`, the script redirects you directly to the page where you can copy the code and after that, you just have to enter it in the console. So I am not clear why the error is on localhost? could you provide more information about that?

Comment: @Emel After I run `node index.js`, the script redirects me to the page where I have to login to my google account. After logging in, it asks me if I want to allow the access from the sheets api app. The error occurs after I click allow.

Comment: So from what I understand, you are not getting the auth code. Have you changed anything in the quick-start code? I have just tested, and it is not reproducible on my side using it. Have you tried using a different web browser? Do you have any logs in the console?

Comment: @Emel Yes you are correct, I am not getting the auth code. I have not changed anything in the quick-start code, I just copy and pasted.  Yes tried a different web browser and no, no logs.

Comment: I guess I should've been more clear. I have made it work in the past. Today, I randomly decided to delete my token and reset my credential and thats when this error happened.

Comment: Can you check if you have the code inside the URL of the localhost?

Comment: `http://localhost/?code=4/0AX4XfWhwGz7a1ervjZ6AlPr-updnc5GpNiZrL8dyAGddCEyjH0lrjPXKGcDPnnT0xGzeVQ&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly` that's what my url looks like. I tried copy and pasting `0AX4XfWhwGz7a1ervjZ6AlPr-updnc5GpNiZrL8dyAGddCEyjH0lrjPXKGcDPnnT0xGzeVQ` and it did not work.

Comment: What error are you receiving ? Please note that the code starts with `4/0...`

Comment: This is totally a diferent error, you have to enable the Sheets API from `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library?project=<your_project_name>`. I will be posting this as an answer, please accept it if you consider it helpful.

Comment: @Emel WELL, I can't thank you enough. Copy and pasting from `4/0...` worked. Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the redirection pointing to your localhost you have the authorization code available inside the URL:

```
http://localhost/?code=<copethiscodetotheconsole>&scope=[listofscopes]
```

Remember to enable the API inside the `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library?project=<your_project_name>`

##### Documentation:

- [Node.js Library](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/#google-apis-nodejs-client)
- [Enabling API Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/enable-api)

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone's still confused by the answer. The solution is to

- First, copy the `auth_code` part from the URL `http://localhost/?code=<auth_code>&scope=[scopes]` .
- And then pasting it on your terminal where you ran your code
- In windows, use might need to use `Windows Key + Shift  + V` to paste to terminal.

The following image shows how the result look like.

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zOsG.png)

- Make sure you also have the Google Sheets API enabled in `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/sheets.googleapis.com?project=<your_project_name>`

[Google Sheets API Enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkLea.png)

After this, your program will be authorized to use Google API

Answer (score 1):

Just like what Emel said, the code is in the url.
Copy and paste and we are good.

Don't forget to enable the sheets api.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I fixed it by finding the line in my code that said `creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)` and changing it to `creds = flow.run_local_server(port=60880)`.

Answer (score 0):

if u are working on google colab Try to use different IDE (local one like VS code)